# Creating a 7 segment LED displaying two numbers (from 0 to 99) using MSP430 Launchpad on Engergia

Tags: arduino

I'm using a Vishay, TDCG1050M for the LED display, a MSP430 Launchpad for the microcontroller, and Energia for the sketch. I have 110 ohm resistors for each pin lighting up the LED and two NPN transistors (one per digit displayed).

I thought the code I have was going to work properly, but the display still isn't correct. The LED display has to read 00 - 99 with the two push buttons attached onto the circuit. The first button increments the value by one while the second button decrements by one. The LED displays values 0-9 correctly, but when it's on 2's and 5's it displays "22" and "55" respectively. When trying to increment (using the button) to "10" the LED displays "0" only, not the 1 in the tens place. The LED does display 20-29 correctly (aside from displaying 25, to which it looks like 55). I've also rewired the whole circuit and it's still reading the same values.

I've tried replacing some wires, transistors, and the LED. I've also tried a new breadboard. I tried two different computers, the first a PC and the second a Mac.

```
#define D1 P2_2 //Display digit 1 control
#define D2 P2_0 //Display digit 2 control 
#define segA P2_6 //Display segment A control
#define segB P8_2 //Display segment B control
#define segC P3_1 //Display segment C control
#define segD P8_1 //Display segment D control
#define segE P2_3 //Display segment E control
#define segF P7_4 //Display segment F control
#define segG P3_7 //Display segment G control
#define digit_pause 2
#define button1 P2_4  
#define button2 P2_5
#define debounceDelay 10

volatile boolean button1_flag = 0;
volatile long lastDebounceTime = 0;
volatile boolean pressed_event_flag = 0;
volatile boolean released_event_flag = 0;

volatile boolean button2_flag = 0;
volatile boolean pressed_event_flag2 = 0;
volatile boolean released_event_flag2 = 0;

int counter = 0;
int number = 0;
int number2 = 0;
int digit = 0;

int digits[] = {D1, D2};
int segments[] {segA, segB, segC, segD, segE, segF, segG};
boolean digit0[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
boolean digit1[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
boolean digit2[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0};
boolean digit3[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0};
boolean digit4[] = {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0};
boolean digit5[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};
boolean digit6[] = {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0};
boolean digit7[] = {0, 0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
boolean digit8[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
boolean digit9[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0};

void setup()
{
    pinMode(button1, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(button1, button1_event, CHANGE);
    pinMode(button2, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(button2, button2_event, CHANGE);
    pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segA, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segB, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segC, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segD, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segE, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segF, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(segG, OUTPUT);

    for(int sweep = 0; sweep < 2; sweep++) {
        digitalWrite(digits[sweep],LOW);
    }
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    if(pressed_event_flag) {
        if (counter <= 99){
            counter++;
        }
    if(pressed_event_flag) {
        if (counter == 100)
            counter=99;
        }
        pressed_event_flag = 0;
    }
    if(released_event_flag) {
        released_event_flag = 0;
    }
    if(pressed_event_flag2) {
        if (counter >= 0){
            counter--;
        }
        pressed_event_flag2 = 0;
    }
    if(released_event_flag2) {
        released_event_flag2 = 0;
    }

    //the problem could be within this part of the code
    delay(2);
    number = counter;
    digit = number % 10;
    digitalWrite(digits[1], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(digits[0], LOW);
    displayDigit(digit);
    delay(5);
    number2 = (number - digit) / 10;
    digitalWrite(digits[0], HIGH);
    digitalWrite(digits[1], LOW);
    displayDigit(number2);
    number2 = (number - digit) / 10;
    delay(5);
}

void displayDigit(int numeral)
{
    switch (numeral) {
    case 0:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit0[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit1[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit2[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit3[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit4[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 5:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit5[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit6[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 7:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit7[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit8[i]);
        }
        break;
    case 9:
        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            digitalWrite(segments[i],digit9[i]);
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
void button1_event()
{
    boolean state = digitalRead(button1); //Determine if pressed or released.
    if(state) {
        if(!button1_flag) {
            if((millis() - lastDebounceTime) >debounceDelay) {
                button1_flag = 1;
                lastDebounceTime = millis();
                pressed_event_flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(button1_flag) {
            if((millis() - lastDebounceTime) >debounceDelay) {
                button1_flag = 0;
                lastDebounceTime = millis();
                released_event_flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
void button2_event()
{
    boolean state = digitalRead(button2); //Determine if pressed or released.
    if(state) {
        if(!button2_flag) {
            if((millis() - lastDebounceTime) >debounceDelay) {
                button2_flag = 1;
                lastDebounceTime = millis();
                pressed_event_flag2 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(button2_flag) {
            if((millis() - lastDebounceTime) >debounceDelay) {
                button2_flag = 0;
                lastDebounceTime = millis();
                released_event_flag2 = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even with your volatiles, why are you testing `if (pressed_event_flag)` inside `if (pressed_event_flag)`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second assignment to number2 is dead code

Comment: Try writing 0-9 to the left digit as if it was the only digit, that will at least check that part of the wiring! = swap the 2 digits controls in the code

Comment: if counter < 99, strict, should save you some lines